# Datastore query two entity kinds, on a common property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have two entity kinds:

```
class image(db.Model):
    url = db.LinkProperty()
    date= db.DateTimeProperty()

class video(db.Model):
    url = db.LinkProperty()
    date= db.DateTimeProperty()
```

Which each may have some other (unimportant here) properties.

What I want to do is somehow merge the queries:

```
i = image.gql('ORDER BY date LIMIT 10')
v = video.gql('ORDER BY date LIMIT 10')
```

Such that I am left with a single `GqlQuery` object that is the result as if `image` and `video` were the same kind.

Is it possible without doing something like:

```
merged = ([a for a in i] + [b for b in v]).sort(key=lambda x: x.date)[:10]
```

Being left with an actual `GqlQuery` object instead of a list of entities would be a plus, though I have everything I need from the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way with inheritance and different classes is to use a PolyModel then your class hierarchy would be

```
class Media(db.Model):
    url = db.LinkProperty()
    date= db.DateTimeProperty()

class Image(Media):
    pass

class Video(Media):
    pass
```

Then in GQL and preferably Query objects

To get all media types

```
 query = Media.query().order(Media.date)
```

To just get Video

```
 query = Video.query().order(Video.date)
```

Or don't have different classes. Have a single Media class and a field that denotes a media type.

Docs for PolyModel can be found here - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass

Comment: Oh that's pretty neat. Are all three classes different entity kinds? i.e. I could have a `Media` entity that isn't `Image` or `Video`, and also have an `Image` entity?

Comment: No they are actually all stored as the same Kind in this case "Media"  but they also store the class name (Video or Image) and any other intermediate classes in the inheritance heirachy.  They are ideal for you application.  There a few gotcha's if you start trying to do weird stuff ;-) so it's worth reading the docs.

Comment: Oh that is exactly built for what I'm trying to achieve, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!